# property is readonly yet members are accessible

Tags: c#, .net

Why I can implement a read-only property like so...

```
public IList<object> SelectedItems { get; }
```

...and still be able to use its members, like Add, Remove, etc. when I use the property ?

Isn't readonly supposed to be readonly "all the way down" ?

Comment: No, readonly is not "all the way down"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> isn't readonly supposed to be readonly "all the way down" ?

1. This isn't a "readonly" type.  It's a property where you can retrieve the value (the `IList<object>`), but can't set the value to a *different instance* of `IList<object>` as there is no property setter.
2. No.  It's not readonly "all the way down" - the fact that the property only has a getter means you can get the value, but you can do anything you wish with it.

Note that I'd be careful using the term "readonly".  C# has a different, distinct meaning and dedicated [`readonly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) keyword, which applies only to *fields*.  This isn't "readonly" in the C# meaning, but a property which only provides a get operation.

If you want to have a "read only" list, a good option is to return a [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  For example, if your internal class is a `List<T>`, you can use:

```
public IList<object> SelectedItems { get { return this.selected.AsReadOnly(); } }
```

If you are going to do this, it might be better to actually return the `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` as well:

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<object> SelectedItems { get { return this.selected.AsReadOnly(); } }
```

This way, users won't *expect* that it's safe to call `.Add()` on the resulting list.

Comment: You probably want to return a `ReadOnlyCollection` here, so as to not confuse users when their code throws exceptions on mutating methods.

Comment: I might not be able to set the actual SelectedItems up front, but I can still say SelectedItems.Add(obj);. I mean, that doesn't seem very readonly, since I add something...

Comment: @danielovich That's why I suggested `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` - however, it might make sense to return `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`, as well, as Servy mentioned.

Comment: @danielovich If you use `AsReadOnly`, as Reed has suggested, then calls to `Add` or `Remove` will throw exceptions at runtime.

Comment: Oh, and depending on how the method is used, it may even make sense to just return an `IEnumerable`.  You loose the indexer, but you don't always need it.

Comment: I am not asking whether it's a readonly type or not, I know it's not :). It's the behaviour of readonly I think is misleading here. The property is readonly but I can still set members on it...to me that's not very readonly.

Comment: @danielovich That's what I'm saying - this isn't a "readonly property", it's a property which allows you to get the value, but not set the value.  The "value" is just the `IList<T>` reference, but has nothing to do with members or data within that reference.

Comment: I got it but I still think it's confusing :) Thanks!

Comment: It should be noted that even a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` is not read-only "all the way down". Because if `T` is some mutable type, you can still mutate each item object. For examle with a `ReadOnlyCollection<Person>` you might say `persons[0].Surname = "Jones";` thereby modifying an object in the collection. (Here `Person` must be a reference type.)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes - very true.